# Scanner не изменяет значение переменной при рекурсии

Tags: java, рекурсия

Почему при выполнении блока if() значение переменной "word" не обновляется?

```
private static String checkTerm(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scanner.nextLine();
    if(map.containsKey(word)){
        System.out.println("The card \"" + word + "\" already exists.Try again:");
        checkTerm();
    }
    return word;
}
```

Comment: потому что вы в блоке if не присваиваете ей новое значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно заменить строчку

```
checkTerm();
```

на

```
word = checkTerm();
```

Когда мы наконец напишем не входящее(в кач-ве ключа) в `map` слово, мы по цепочке возратим его. Вы же это слово не "ловите" - ссылка на String улетает в пустоту сборщика мусора за отсутствием ссылки на данный объект.